# MySQL variable name conflicts with field name

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure for MySQL which needs to have an input parameter that has the same name as a field in a table. I know that I can refer to the field as `tableName.fieldName`. But how can I refer to the **variable** in a non-ambiguous way when querying that table within the procedure?

```
Table files
+----+---------+---------+
| id | ownerId | content |
+----+---------+---------+

CREATE PROCEDURE getFilesOfOwner(IN ownerId INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM files WHERE files.ownerId = ___________      <- ?
  ...
```

Comment: And why do you have to use the same name for the parameter? You can prepend it with `@` or `p_` for example.

Comment: Because the arguments of the procedure should have the names best matching their purpose and someone calling the procedure should not need to be bothered with strange identifiers or with what happens inside the procedure.

Comment: That's the strangest argument I've ever heard. So the "someone" who's calling the procedure will have a problem with `@school_id` or `p_school_id` and will only understand `school_id`? Using the same name for different objects in your code is the best source for bugs, assuming you can get it to work in the first place.

Comment: Following your logic, if you had 3 tables all referencing a school, you would have to name those fields `school_id`, `_school_id` and `p_school_id`. Nobody does that. Any decent developer **will** use the same names across all tables when they are referencing the same field. Your `p_school_id` is an ugly workaround, besides, it's not even answering the question. I asked specifically for a non-ambiguous syntax in the case when two identifiers have the **same name**.

Comment: Why would you need 3 names, I don't follow. There is no issue in using the same name for fields that belong to different tables, and yes of course all developers even the novice ones use the same name in those cases. I was suggesting names for the parameters, not the fields. What does this have to do with that? My point was: **do not use the same name for different identifiers in the same code. That would be confusing and source for bugs that are hard to find**.

Comment: Please do **read the question**! It states "how can I refer to the variable in a **non-ambiguous** way". You keep repeating that refering to it in an **ambiguous** way would be a bad idea. Well, of course! That's why I asked, duh!

Comment: OK, got it, thanks for the explanation. So the answer is **there is no unambiguous way to do that**. I'm not sure how this comment is different from my previous comments, but it seems you prefer it worded in this unambiguous way, so here you have it. Good luck!

Comment: This is like someone asking "I need to get from Berlin to Washington, what's the best connection?" and you answering "Why do you have to go to Washington? You can go to London for example"... the question clearly stated that the parameter name is a given, and there is a solution for that (see answer)

Comment: And your answer was downvoted, why do you think? Your question is not like that, it is like *I need to get from Berlin to Washington swimming in a safe way*, and my answer was *you cannot do it swimming in a safe way, why don't you take a plane?* :). Forget about MySQL, you cannot call two guys sitting in the same room using the exact name in an unambiguous way, or can you? Believe me, my first comment is the best answer you can get, why would anybody want to do that? You're trying to do something that makes no sense, and you'll achieve nothing but nonsense. Take it or leave it.

Comment: Well, I said that (1) the parameter name needs to be equal to the field name and (2) I don't want ambiguity in the query. All you answered is correct, but contradicts (1), so it's not helpful. I respect that you would rather change the parameter name, but that is a mere matter of preference. The question itself is perfectly valid, and it has a correct and working answer, given below. If you think there is something wrong with it, feel free to offer a re-stated question or answer. But anything violating (1) or (2) relates to a different question than this one.

Comment: Yes, your last comment finally described the situation perfectly. I was saying that you couldn't get (1) and (2) at the same time, and since (2) is more important, I suggested to drop (1). I was trying to help you by telling you that the route you're taking could lead to bugs. Sadly downvoters never leave comments, so there is no way to know why your answer was downvoted, but perhaps for the same reason. However, it's your project, so if you're happy with the solution that you found, then go with it, but I suggest to add a comment in the SP for the future.

Comment: Glad we finally agree :) Dropping (1), I'd have to change the old identifier in 9 places it's already used in, clutter the schema's version control diff with changes that don't change anything and update the documentation. I much prefer just adding one line of code to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I see, that's why we always add a prefix to all SP parameters, to avoid any possible conflict, now and in the future. Consider adding the info from your last comment to the question to make it more useful and hopefully attract some upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the name of a procedure argument is the same as a field name of a table, using that identifier in a query to that table will be interpreted by MySQL as a reference to the variable, i.e. no qualifier is formally needed, however this is a vendor-specific conflict resolution only.

The solution for keeping the argument name the same is to declare an alias variable **within** the scope of the procedure, but expose it to the caller under the desired name:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getFilesOfOwner(IN ownerId INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE _ownerId INT DEFAULT ownerId;
  SELECT * FROM files WHERE files.ownerId = _ownerId
  ...
```

This requires one additional line of code, but it keeps the procedure signature clean from implementation-specific details.

Comment: Are you sure? [This newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64499315/2757035) says the exact opposite, and the question demonstrates that: that it is the _column name_ that takes precedence and wins, not the argument name.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, and a MySQL employee [confirmed on the MySQL forums](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,21390,22194#msg-22194) that the argument name takes precedence. The code in my question DOES work, but I consider it bad coding style because it's ambiguous and you would have to know the precedence order to understand what it does. The code in my answer fixes this. The answer you are referring to is wrong about that particular aspect (yet it's still a working solution for the other question).