# how to do an update, delete and select using Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-update, sql-delete

When I try to use an update, delete or select, the code executes the commands in all rows.

#### Update example

```
   DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_cinema
(IN NOME_FANTASIA varchar(100), IN LOGRADOURO varchar(100),IN CIDADE varchar(100), IN ESTADO varchar(100),IN LOTACAO int, in ID_CINEMA int)
BEGIN
UPDATE tb_cinema
SET NOME_FANTASIA = nome_fantasia , LOGRADOURO=LOGRADOURO, CIDADE= cidade, ESTADO= estado, LOTACAO= lotacao
WHERE id_cinema = id_cinema;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL UPDATE_CINEMA ('Muda', 'Por favor', 'da certo', 'MS', 400, 16)
```

[The update executes in 16,17 and 18 instead of only in 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lxZn.png)

#### Select example

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_cinema
(IN NOME_FANTASIA varchar(100))
BEGIN
SELECT * from tb_cinema
 where nome_fantasia = nome_fantasia;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[It is selecting all rows instead of the row that i choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nblsV.png)

#### Delete example

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE DELETE_CINEMA
(IN NOME_FANTASIA varchar(100))
BEGIN
DELETE  from tb_cinema
 where nome_fantasia = nome_fantasia;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

call DELETE_cinema ('test_Select')
```

[It is deleting all rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJBkP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need give the parameter names that are different from the actual column names. Otherwise, it is ambiguous whether the name refer to the parameter or the column name. As a consequence, the `where` conditions become no-ops, just like the `set` assignments.

Here is an example for the update procedure. I prefixed all parameter names with `p_` to remove the ambiguity:

```
create procedure update_cinema(
    in p_nome_fantasia varchar(100), 
    in p_logradouro varchar(100),
    in p_cidade varchar(100), 
    in p_estado varchar(100),
    in p_lotacao int, 
    in p_id_cinema int
)
begin
    update tb_cinema
    set 
        nome_fantasia = p_nome_fantasia, 
        logradouro = p_logradouro, 
        cidade = p_cidade, 
        estado = p_estado, 
        lotacao = p_lotacao
    where id_cinema = p_id_cinema;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695484/2757035), which says that instead the parameter gets the precedence, is wrong?

Comment: The above answer by GMB is wrong about the precedence order. MySQL resolves the ambiguity by prioritizing the *argument name*, not the column name, as was [confirmed by a MySQL employee](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,21390,22194#msg-22194). Nevertheless, the answer by GMB still offers a working solution to the question. The answer referred to by underscore_d is correct.

Comment: @travelboy: thanks. I modified slitghtly the answer. Actually, regardless of whether the table column or the variable takes precedence. the filtering becomes a no-op in both cases.