# The procedure is not working correctly as I expected in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The task is to create a procedure that has 2 inputs (in Category_Id tinyint unsigned, in Language_Id tinyint unsigned). And there are 3 cases:

- Case 1: if Category_Id = 0 then show all film info that has the same Language_Id.
- Case 2: if Language_Id = 0 then show all film info that has the same Category_Id.
- Case 3: Else show all film info that has the same Language_Id and Category_Id.

I'm using sakila database.
This is my code

```
drop procedure if exists `displayFilmInfo`;

delimiter $$
create procedure displayFilmInfo (in Category_Id tinyint unsigned,
                                in Language_Id tinyint unsigned)
begin
if Category_Id = 0 then
select * from film 
where language_id = Language_Id;
else if Language_Id = 0 then
    select film.* from
    film join film_category
    on film.film_id = film_category.film_id
    where category_id = Category_Id;
    else
        select film.* from
        film join film_category
        on film.film_id = film_category.film_id
        where category_id = Category_Id
        and film.language_id = Language_Id;
    end if;
end if;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

But when I try with different inputs, it always returns 1000 rows.

Comment: See [MySQL variable name conflicts with field name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48692597) (e.g. your variable name cannot be the same as your column name).

Comment: It works. It looks like MySQL can't differentiate between Upper_Case and upper_case.